# [WinError 2]FileNotFoundError in python Selenium webDriver

Tags: python, selenium, web, webdriver

I'm started to learn python Selenium. I just downloaded by pip `pip install python-selenium` and started to write first lines and at this moment appeares

```
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
>>> driver = webdriver.Firefox()
[WinError2] FileNotFoundError...
...
```

Then I tried it with Chrome but appeares the same thing. Who can solve this problem?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You do following things and check whether it works.
Upgrade python bindings using

```
pip install -U selenium
```

for chrome download the latest chrome driver "ChromeDriver 2.45"
and write the code

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver=webdriver.Chrome("Path of the Chromedriver" + "chromedriver.exe" )
```